# Duplicate fields name in join result in Dapper + Oracle in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

I'm doing test in Dapper + Oracle in C#

the sample tables as below

**Book**

```
+----+----------------+-----------+
| id |     title      | author_id |
+----+----------------+-----------+
|  1 | this is a book |         2 |
+----+----------------+-----------+
```

**Author**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  2 | Mark |
+----+------+
```

my code:

```
string queryString = "SELECT distinct * FROM book b INNER JOIN author a ON a.id = b.author_id";
var result = connection.Query(queryString);
```

the output:

```
{DapperRow, id = 1, title='this is a book', author_id = 2, id = 2, name = 'Mark'}
```

there are two fields with duplicate name "id" in result

how could I add alias or postfix to the duplicate fields like the output in sqldeveloper like below

```
+----+----------------+-----------+------+------+
| id |     title      | author_id | id_1 | name |
+----+----------------+-----------+------+------+
|  1 | this is a book |         2 |    2 | Mark |
+----+----------------+-----------+------+------+
```

thanks

Comment: Don't use `*` - just list the fields you want to retrive, i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT b.id, b.title, b.author_id, a.name ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use aliases in select statement:

```
string queryString = "SELECT distinct b.id [book_id], ... FROM book b INNER JOIN author a ON a.id = b.author_id";
```